# JAVA: Classloader not reading manifest

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classloader, manifest

I have a piece of code which loads A.jar using a urlclassloader. A.jar contains a manifest file which looks like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-path: gf.javax.jms-1.1.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar spring-aop-
3.0.7.RELEASE.jar spring-asm-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar spring-beans-3.0.7.REL
EASE.jar spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar spring-context-support-3.0.
7.RELEASE.jar spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar spring-expression-3.0.7.R
ELEASE.jar gf.javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar 1padapters-mapping.jar 1padapter
s-jms-resolvers.jar 1padapters-util.jar javax.jms.jar
```

The classloader loads the classes within the jar fine, however, as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html states in the second example, the classes in the above jars referenced by name should also be added to the class path when I load A.jar using the classloader, however this doesn't happen, and if I try to access a class in one of these referenced jars I get a ClassNotFound exception. The jars in the classpath header are in the same directory as A.jar, and there is a newline at the end of my manifest file. Why aren't the jars in the classpath header added to the classpath of my loader?